# task running in ec2(spot-fleet) don't use more then 32GB of memory in ECS AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Why task(docker) don't use more than `32GB` of ec2, with more than `32GB` available in ec2 and task definition?

I don't know why docker doesn't use more than `32GB`, because I use an ec2 with `122GB`, and I declared in the task definition that the task has `122GB` of RAM.

I execute a task with:

```
Task memory (MiB)121000
Task CPU (unit)3900
```

Running in ECS cluster, ec2(spot-fleet) x1e.xlarg with:

```
Task memory (MiB)122000
Task CPU (unit)4000
```

But when I see `docker stats` of this task running, the docker doesn't use more than `32GB memory`.

**Spot Fleet configuration**

```
   amzn2-ami-ecs-gpu-hvm-2.0.20200706-x86_64-ebs [ami-082692cd7634df346]

   User-data

   #!/bin/bash
   echo "ECS_CLUSTER=tor-privoxy" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Comment: Please explicitly state your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such limitation of memory for ECS task, I will recommend removing memory restriction so your task will able to use `Maximum` memory of underlying EC2 instance if required.

Just use `memoryReservation` parameter and remove `memory` configuration from the task defintion.

```
memoryReservation
Type: integer

Required: no
```

> The soft limit (in MiB) of memory to reserve for the container. When system memory is under contention, Docker attempts to keep the container memory to this soft limit; however, **your container can consume more memory when needed, up to either the hard limit specified with the memory parameter (if applicable)**, or all of the available memory on the container instance, whichever comes first. This parameter maps to `MemoryReservatio`n in the Create a container section of the Docker Remote API and the `--memory-reservation` option to docker run.

[container_definition_memory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_memory)

Once you launch the container with this setting you will able to see the  `MEM USAGE / LIMIT` where `limit` will show max memory of your EC2 instance in response of `docker stats`

[image]